# Compact, up to date, LiveCD supporting LUKS and ZfsOnLinux

Tags: linux, livecd, zfs

I'm looking for a nice compact LivecD to support a new installation.  The Gentoo minimal install CD is about the perfect thing, except it does not support ZFS.  The Gentoo LiveDVD does Support both cryptsetup/LUKS and ZFS, but does not have the newest builds (cannot mount an updated ZFS pool from ZfsOnLinux 0.6.2).

Ideally I would be able to use this to install Gentoo onto a machine with bare disks, and also to boot and mount those disks later should the need arise.

Comment: Of course not. I told you you have to install zfs, It is very easy, see the instructions here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS_Installation

Comment: Sorry, I forgot: the package manager in Arch Linux is pacman. The command to install is `sudo pacman -S package_name`, the list of packages to install is in the reference above.

Comment: If you are interested, I can later help you modify the install image to include these packages, so that when you burn the image to USB stick you will already have them.

Comment: You said building a custom ISO "may [be] helpful" not, "you must build a custom ISO to add ZFS support".  P.S. these comments are threaded in the wrong place.

Comment: In fact, you do not have to. You may install those commands every time you need them. Or, if you use them very often, you may build a custom ISO. What do you mean by `threaded in the wrong place`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to build a Gentoo install CD with ZFS support added:
http://linux.arantius.com/building-a-gentoo-minimal-livecd-with-zfs-support

This meant finding the Gentoo "releng" project, and updating it to add the ZFS tools and modules into the build:
https://github.com/arantius/gentoo-releng/compare/master...zfs

Answer (score 0):

Why not try Arch Linux? It definitely has support for `zfs` and `LUKS`. You can find relevant installation information in the [Installation Guide Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_Guide), which has links to (among many other things) [disk encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption) and [file systems](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_Systems#Step_2:_create_the_new_file_system%5C), where you find confirmation of support for both LUKS and zfs. Also, this being Arch Linux, it is usually the first distro to get the new builds. Lastly, it has clear instructions on [how to build a custom iso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Building_a_Live_CD), which you may find helpful, given your rather specific demands.

Comment: I've downloaded and booted archlinux-2013.12.01-dual.iso in a virtual machine, and neither the zpool nor zfs commands exist.